# Oauth token and creds

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce, workday-api

One of the enterprise integration tools i am working with has a salesforce connector. But the connector has oathtoken, username and password all these 3 fields as required fields. My understanding was that, with an oauth token a uname pwd combination is not reauired. I was able to make the calls required to salesforce using this oauth token via postman. Any idea why this tool is requiring all three fields?  The tool in question is workday studio.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, username or password shouldn't be needed for OAuth flow. I know nothing about Workday but are you sure it's **OAuth** token it wants?

It sounds like your tool is using old-school SOAP API. This works with username, password and optional **security** token. You can generate it in setup and it'll come in an email message. There are situations when you don't need it (for example logging in from trusted IP) but if it's a required field... Stupid Workday rule, try to generate it anyway? Read more https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

So yeah, I'd try with that. And then check what do you see in Setup -> Login History in Salesforce? It should say whether it's SOAP or REST API, OAuth or not... My gut feel is it'll say SOAP. If it'd be OAuth it'd either not ask for password at all (just show you "allow access" screen) or ask for few more things (client id, secret)... There are many OAUth flows possible with Salesforce, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm

P.S. Welcome to StackOverflow. No idea who downwoted you without leaving any comment, I gave you +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OAuth2.0 then I hope you have the endpoints Client ID, Client Secret, Username, Password from external API.
You have to make two API calls in Studio,

1. First call is to pass the credentials & get the "**Access token**"
2. Make the second call with Access token to get the data.
   The access token have minimum validity time(Confirm with if it's possible to increase validity of the access token, If that's possible then you only have to make the second call).